# How to block a change of state for an order transaction?

Tags: shopware

I am dealing with a Shopware6 plugin for a payment gateway. I have to handle the change of the state for the order transaction.
In one of my case, I would like to prevent the change of state in `Refunded` for an order transaction when I am trying to perform a refund on a payment provider and I receive an error.

I found this method `\Shopware\Core\System\StateMachine\StateMachineRegistry::transition`

```
public function transition(Transition $transition, Context $context): StateMachineStateCollection
{
  ...
  $repository->upsert($data, $context);
  ...
  $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(new StateMachineTransitionEvent(...));
  ...
  $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(...);
  ...
  $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(...);
  ...
}
```

where more than one event is dispatched, but all of them after the `upsert`.

Even if I raise an Exception in a subscriber of those events, the upsert already updated the db table and I have no chance to revert it, especially because the `Refunded` state is a no exit state.

How can I prevent or revert the upsert?

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the upsert. For that you would need to write a new transition to the database.

The table you are looking for is *state_machine_transition* and how the data is written to that table can be found under *platform/src/Core/Migration/Migration1536233560BasicData.php@1078*. You will need to do this in your plugin migration.

Then you could transition the state again after it was changed to your edgecase.